# Plain DataSource to Nested Lists c#

Tags: c#, nested, sqldatareader, simplify

It all starts with a Stored Procedure data result *(plain structure)*:

> *IdGrandad, GrandadName, IdDad, DadName, IdChild, ChildName*

*The response should be a nested entities list.*

I get the data into a **SqlDataReader**... then, here comes the loop:

```
var grandadList = new List<Grandad>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    // Properties setters.
    Grandad grandadItem = BindGrandad(reader);
    Dad dadItem = BindDad(reader);
    Child childItem = BindChild(reader);

    // Entities finders.
    Func<Grandad, bool> foundGrandad = (item => item.Identity.Equals(grandadItem.Identity));
    Func<Dad, bool> foundDad = (item => item.Identity.Equals(dadItem.Identity));

    if (!grandadList.Any(foundGrandad))
        grandadList.Add(grandadItem);

    // Here comes the horror-code...
    if (!grandadList.Where(foundGrandad).SelectMany(item => item.DadList).ToList().Any(foundDad))
        grandadList.SingleOrDefault(foundGrandad)?
            .DadList.Add(dadItem);

    grandadList.SingleOrDefault(foundGrandad)?
        .DadList.SingleOrDefault(foundDad)?
        .ChildList.Add(childItem);
}
```

Any idea of how can I simplify the loop code?

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, no answers at all!.

Well, I've just found a "better" solution...

> You should create a plain object first, then let the **.GroupBy()** do the
>   trick!.

Read you later.